# ServiceStack throws StackOverflowException when receiving large data

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, servicestack, stack-overflow

I am using ServiceStack's JsonServiceClient with Silverlight 5 to receive JSON data from my ASP.Net server. It works perfectly for short JSON strings but when it comes to very large amounts of data, a StackOverflowException is thrown in `ServiceStack.ServiceClient.Web.AsyncServiceClient.ReadCallBack<>`.

So I examined the latest source code on [GitHub](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.Common/ServiceClient.Web/AsyncServiceClient.cs#L495) and noticed that the data is read block-wise from a stream as chunks of [4096 bytes](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.Common/ServiceClient.Web/AsyncServiceClient.cs#L47). The problem is that this method reads a block and tells the stream to call itself recursively when done. The more data we receive, the more recursive calls occur. That's why the application crashes when the received data is too large.

Ideas:

- Refactor the method to be iterative rather than recursive. Seems like a hard task to do with all these conditional returns, awaits, try-catch and such.
- Increase the block size. I don't know if there are any reasons for 4096
  here, so I'd rather not do this alone.

Anyway, before I download all the source code, modify and compile it myself, I'd like to hear your opinion on this. Is it a bug or am I using it wrong?

Comment: Hopefully mythz will have a look at it soon. I had this problem a few times, too. Please let us know if you found a solution.

Comment: Yikes.  Recursive calls to handle unbounded streams? :(

Comment: I've just doubled the default buffer size and made it configurable [in this commit](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/commit/2ae0577c72de7bae279796f3b7131f77ff56260e). It currently supports multiple async patterns so it will be too error prone to re-factor it without recursion, will look into it after we upgrade to .NET 4.0 and remove APM callbacks. Out of curiosity how big was the response that threw StackOverflowExceptions?

Comment: Thank you. I will try the new commit. A response of 17.5397 MB throws the exception while 11.9957 MB doesn't. Unfortunately I can't figure it out more accurately right now.

Comment: The new version works with our response sizes. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

There is a limitation on the string length that gets sent across the wire for your JSON response. On an external application it is likely you would never hit the default limit. However, on internal apps you may hit it since the weight is not such and issue. You need to add the following in your web.config file to max out the JSON string length.

Note that you cannot set the string length the unlimited. Also, I don't think you can go above 2147483644.

```
<configuration> 
 <system.web.extensions>
   <scripting>
       <webServices>
           <jsonSerialization maxJsonLength="2147483644"/>
       </webServices>
   </scripting>
 </system.web.extensions>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always create a new thread and pass stack size to it's constructor
That will always works
Notice that in some situations such as ASP.NET development, you have very small stack trace size by default.
Good luck